# limit - mysql query

Tags: mysql, limit

I would like to know how can i limit the output by the number of id_offers and not the number of rows. For example

```
 SELECT  A.id_offer, T.tags  
            FROM offer A
            INNER JOIN offer_has_tags Z
            ON A.id_offer = Z.offer_id_offer

            INNER JOIN tags T
            ON Z.tags_id_tags = T.id_tags

            WHERE state = 0 
            ORDER BY date
            DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```

output:

```
  id_offer  tags
    77       xx 
    76       xx 
    76       xx 
    75       xx 
    75       xx 
    74       xx 
    74       xx
    73       xx
    73       xx
    72       xx
```

Edit: In this case only should be count as 6 offers.

Comment: You need a UNIQUE in there somewhere. Not quite able to follow your field names and their relationships, so I can't offer up where.

Comment: Which table does the `state` belong?

Comment: It belongs to offer table. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is exactly what you want, but I think it is:

```
SELECT  A.id_offer, T.tags  
FROM offer A
JOIN offer_has_tags Z
  ON A.id_offer = Z.offer_id_offer
JOIN tags T
  ON Z.tags_id_tags = T.id_tags
JOIN (
    SELECT DISTINCT id_offer
    FROM offer
    WHERE state = 0
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 10
) L
  ON A.id_offer = L.id_offer
```

or the more simple:

```
SELECT  A.id_offer, T.tags  
FROM 
  ( SELECT *
    FROM offer
    WHERE state = 0
    ORDER BY date DESC
    LIMIT 10
  ) A
JOIN offer_has_tags Z
  ON A.id_offer = Z.offer_id_offer
JOIN tags T
  ON Z.tags_id_tags = T.id_tags
```

Comment: Give me an syntax error in subquery:  SELECT UNIQUE id_offer FROM offer and another issue: this version of MySQL doesn't yet support 'LIMIT & IN/ALL/ANY/SOME subquery'

Comment: I forgot that MySQL doesn't allow `LIMIT` on subqueries.  Converting to a join (like in my updated answer) may fix the problem.  And s/UNIQUE/DISTINCT/

Comment: unfortunately didn't works. It shows the tags for all offers. GROUP_CONCAT can maybe help to count the number of id_offers ?

Comment: @galador: You probably need the `WHERE state = 0` in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
SELECT  A.id_offer, T.tags  
FROM offer A
    INNER JOIN offer_has_tags Z
        ON A.id_offer = Z.offer_id_offer
    INNER JOIN tags T
        ON Z.tags_id_tags = T.id_tags

WHERE (state = 0) AND
      (A.id_offer >= 72 AND A.id_offer <= 77)
ORDER BY date
```

Comment: i don't know the id of the offers

Answer (score 0):

You simply have to use DISTINCT:

SELECT  **DISTINCT** A.id_offer, T.tags
            FROM offer A
            INNER JOIN offer_has_tags Z
            ON A.id_offer = Z.offer_id_offer

```
        INNER JOIN tags T
        ON Z.tags_id_tags = T.id_tags

        WHERE state = 0 
        ORDER BY date
        DESC LIMIT 0, 10
```